# Intellij: Error while importing SBT project

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, intellij-plugin

I used Intellij for 4 months without any problems. Yesterday I installed it on another PC but I can't create a SBT Scala project.

Here the steps:

I create the project:
[image: NewProject]

When started it says me that "SBT project need to be imported" so I click on "Enable Auto-Import" but then I get this error:
[image: SBT error]

If I try to add Scala SDK from modules settings I get this error:
[image: Modules error]

I downloaded Scala and SBT externally, I also tried all the suggested solutions from other similar threads but I can't resolve it.
How can I do?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I also hit this exact same thing in the past 2 hours. When I hit it the 1st time, decided to clean the machine and re-try. Un-installed Java, IntelliJ, searched hard drive for all folders named things like Sun, Java, Oracle, Jetbrains, IntelliJ, .sbt, .ivy etc and deleted those. Ran CCleaner's reg-cleaner repeatedly until no junk was left in the registry. Rebooted, re-downloaded fresh Java 9 + fresh IntelliJ, reinstalled Java 9, reinstalled IntelliJ Community, got the same exact error.  Could it be Java 9 is too new to use here?

Comment: @brucer10 thank you for the answer! You are right: I installed JDK 8 and now it works!

Comment: Weird, my question of Java 9 was a crazy-wild guess. Thanks for saying Java 8 worked for you, that prompted me to try Java 8 - works here too. I sent off a note to IntelliJ support. Then I noticed at scala.org it does say to use Java 8. Oh well, complex world today, who knows, maybe Java 9 works fine already except somebody needs to kick one last content-delivery-network node somewhere, make it refresh its cache.

Answer (score 0):

Add sbt.version to `project/build.properties`.  You can check SBT version using `sbt sbtVersion`.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but IntelliJ+SBT are once again doing all that stuff for me now that I moved back to Java 8.